# How to write this is RegEx format for java to use the the pattern.compile

Tags: java, regex, string

So for my assignment, I need to check the input if it is in the correct format and have no other information. I found out about using regex and the Pattern and the `compile` function, but I just need this code in regex format. I looked up stuff on the internet and figured this
 part out

```
1. For phone : ( ### ) - ### - ###
2. Name :  Abc Def
3. Email :  abc.def@ghi.com

Name: [A-Z][a-z]+[ ][A-Z][a-z]+ 
Phone : ([0-9][0-9][0-9])-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] 
Email : [a-z]([a-z])*(.[a-z]+)*@[a-z]+.(a-z)+
```

For Email:

```
String emailRegex = "\"^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$\""; 

//this is just some random code that I dont even understand     
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);      
if (pattern.matcher(email).matches()) {             
     System.out.println(email);
}else {
    //Further processing
}
```

> So I just need to figure out how to convert it into Regex code that I can use it to compare it to the input string*

Comment: you need to start reading about java regex and experimenting one step at a time. Start with 'name', then phone number, then the email. Let us know when you stuck.

Comment: "// this is just some random code that I dont even understand" which part is not clear/confuses you?

Comment: I would, but Im in java 2 which is like intro to comp sci. No one taught me anything and I've talked to my prof but it makes no sense. So frustrating

Comment: @Pshemo I copied that off google and tried using it but I don't understand how to create a Regex with the given formula :

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't understand how to create a Regex with the given formula"? What formula you have in mind? Your example holds regex formula for email in `String emailRegex = "..."` which is used as base to create `Pattern` via `Pattern.compile(emailRegex)`. This Pattern instance can later validate many inputs by creating Matcher for each input via `pattern.matcher(emailToValidate)` and then calling on it `matches()` which checks if pattern can match whole string held by `emailToValidate`.

Comment: For more info read official regex tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ and documentation of each method used in your example (just notice that `matcher(..)` belongs to Pattern class, and `matches` to `Matcher`)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out what question I ha and the solution to this.